# Problem when using REGEX to extract from DB to CSV

Tags: python, regex, database

I have a DataBase in HTML from I am trying to extract information to a CSV file.

The format of the HTML is like this:

```
<tr style = "background:#D8EBEA"><td>2</td><td>GCF_000022565.1_ASM2256v1_protein.faa.gz</td><td colspan = 4>Acidobacterium capsulatum ATCC 51196</td></tr>
<tr style = "background:#D8EBEA"><td>Taxonomy</td><td colspan = 5>Acidobacteria; Acidobacteriia; Acidobacteriales; Acidobacteriaceae; Acidobacterium; Acidobacterium capsulatum</td></tr>
<tr style = "background:#D8EBEA"><td>First 60 AAs</td><td colspan = 5>MKSISRRSFVTTAAAGMAALGSLGPALPAAQGQAVEMASDWDISSFNQLAQSPARVKQLF</td></tr>
<tr style = "background:#D8EBEA"><td>WP_012680923.1</td><td colspan = 5>Tat pathway signal sequence domain-containing protein [Acidobacterium capsulatum]</td></tr>
<tr style = "background:#D8EBEA"><td>TMHMM</td><td>WP_012680923.1</td><td colspan = 4>Length: 237</td>
<tr style = "background:#D8EBEA"><td>TMHMM</td><td>WP_012680923.1</td><td colspan = 4>Number of predicted TMHs:  1</td>
<tr style = "background:#D8EBEA"><td>TMHMM</td><td>WP_012680923.1</td><td colspan = 4>Exp number of AAs in TMHs: 31.62059</td>
<tr style = "background:#D8EBEA"><td>TMHMM</td><td>WP_012680923.1</td><td colspan = 4>Exp number, first 60 AAs:  5.92535</td>
<tr style = "background:#D8EBEA"><td>TMHMM</td><td>WP_012680923.1</td><td colspan = 4>Total prob of N-in:        0.86701</td>
<tr style = "background:#D8EBEA">
<td>TMHMM</td>
<td>WP_012680923.1</td>
<td>WP_012680923.1</td>
<td>inside</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>205</td>
</tr>
<tr style = "background:#D8EBEA">
<td>TMHMM</td>
<td>WP_012680923.1</td>
<td>WP_012680923.1</td>
<td>TMhelix</td>
<td>206</td>
<td>228</td>
</tr>
<tr style = "background:#D8EBEA">
<td>TMHMM</td>
<td>WP_012680923.1</td>
<td>WP_012680923.1</td>
<td>outside</td>
<td>229</td>
<td>237</td>
</tr>
```

I am using this python code to extract

```
import re

class ProteinHtml:
  __fileName = None
  __contentFile = None

  def __init__(self, fileName):
    self.__fileName = fileName
    with open(fileName) as f:
      self.__contentFile = f.read()

  def getFileName(self):
    return self.__fileName

  def searchProtein(self, proteinName):
    regexBegin = "<tr style = \"background:#[\w\d]+\"><td>WP_[\d]+\.1<\/td><td colspan = 5>.*serine.protease(.*"
    regexEnd = ".*)<\/td><\/tr>"
    regex = regexBegin + proteinName + regexEnd
    count = sum(1 for match in re.finditer(r"{}".format(regex),
      self.__contentFile))
    return count

  def findAllProteinNames(self):
    allProteins = {}
     regex = "<tr style = \"background:#[\w\d]+\"><td>(WP_[\d]+\.1)<\/td><td colspan = 5>(.*Tat.pathway.)*<\/td><\/tr>"
    for match in re.finditer(r"{}".format(regex), self.__contentFile):
      protein = match.group(1)
      if (protein in allProteins):
        allProteins[protein] += 1
      else:
        allProteins.update({protein: 1})
    return allProteins
```

The problem is that REGEX is only giving me the first information in `()`

> regex = "<tr style =
> "background:#[\w\d]+">**(WP_[\d]+.1)**</td>(.*Tat.pathway.)*</td></tr>"

So right now I need to use two scripts one for WP and another for protein name...

> regex = "<tr style =
> "background:#[\w\d]+">**(WP_[\d]+.1)**</td>.*Tat.pathway.*</td></tr>"
>
> regex = "<tr style ="background:#[\w\d]+">WP_[\d]+.1</td>**(.*Tat.pathway.)***</td></tr>"

Is there any way to obtain both things in one script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From python [match.group](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.group)

> Returns one or more subgroups of the match. If there is a single argument, the result is a single string; if there are multiple arguments, the result is a tuple with one item per argument. Without arguments, group1 defaults to zero (the whole match is returned).

On your string

```
regex = "<tr style = "background:#[\w\d]+">(WP_[\d]+.1)</td>(.Tat.pathway.)</td></tr>"
```

you have two regex groups, but in the code you are using `match.group(1)` which return only the first group. You can get the remaing group with:

```
wp_num = match.group(1)
prot_name = match.group(2)
```